# Querying entities by (automapped) DTO fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, kendo-ui, automapper

I have an entity which I'm mapping to a DTO using AutoMapper. This DTO contains some fields which are not direct fields of the entity. For instance:

```
class PersonDto
{
  public string AddressStreet {get; set;} // Is mapped to Person.Address.Street
  public int FriendsCount {get; set;} // Person.Friends.Count
  //etc...
}
```

Now I am displaying a list of these DTOs in a Kendo grid in the front end (Kendo itself is not necessarily relevant to this question - a custom solution would do roughly the same thing). Kendo lets you filter and sort a grid by the column properties. So if a user selects a filter,the backend gets a List request containing a filter parameter like this:

```
filter = 
    {
      Field = "FriendsCount",
      Operator = "greaterthan",
      Value = "5"
    }
```

Now, as I would like to avoid enormous filter functions where I run a switch over the Field and Operator in every request, I would like to use reflection in the Linq query where I compare `entity.Field` to `filter.Value`. This is doable, but obviously doesn't work if the DTOs fields are not direct fields on the entity itself (as there is no FriendsCount property on Person).

**So my question is: Can I somehow filter entities by fields of their DTOs?** Something like `PersonSet.where(x => GetDto(x).Field == filter.Value)` would be perfect but this won't work in Linq, as it can't be converted to SQL. Is there some kind of alternative through AutoMapper? Something like the `ProjectTo<Dto>` function which allows me to run a query on DTOs instead of entities?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes, use the DTO as the grid datasource. In your Read, project to the DTO. In your updates, fetch the entity, map the changes, update, refresh the DTO, return to grid.